# Proper format for 11:59 time for Cronjob in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am trying to figure out how to one have my cronjob run at 11:59 every day and also how to start the job atleast once before that time here is what I have so far

```
var job = new CronJob( '*/10 * * * * *',

 async function f() {

   obj = array[index++ % array.length]

    let tweet =  await client.tweets.findTweetById(obj, {"expansions": "author_id"})

    console.log(JSON.stringify(tweet))

    t = JSON.stringify(tweet)
   
},null,
true,
'America/Chicago'
);
job.start()
```

Comment: The crontab syntax for 11.59 every day is `59 11 * * *`. What exactly do you mean by _"at least once before that time"_?

Comment: so what my code kinda does is it cycles through an array every time the cronjob is called I  want to make it so that it starts at the first item in the array before the cronjob is even called so that I can have the server put that as the starting response right now if I make a get request before the cronjob is called I will get an error because there is nothing defined yet so I was wondering if there was an option within the cron function to run this function once before it even actually runs at 11:59

Comment: I guess though what I could do is just call the function in my cronjob one time before I start the actual cronjob so the array could just start at the first object